# OnReceive not being called as it should

Tags: android, networking, wifi

Through searching around on SO, I found a way to scan wifi networks in the area and to display those results through a TextView. Here is the code:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wifinetworks);
    mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    mainText.setText("");

    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()==false)
    {
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, intentFilter);
    mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");
    mWifiManager.startScan();
}



public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(debugString, "I am in onRecieve");
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
        mainText.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
            String info = (wifiScanList.get(i).toString());
            mainText.append(info + "\n\n");
        }
    }

}
```

The log statement never seems to get called, and I have the following permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

What could be going wrong here? Appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT: I realized that I had not declared my receiver in the manifest so I made a WifiReceiver class (changes are above) and declared it like so:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.alexander.bluetoothcontroller.MainActivity$WifiReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

However, this still did not change anything unless I am missing something in the declaration. I also added the extra permission that was suggested but still nothing has changed. I did notice this callstack that stood out to me in logcat:

08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/WifiHW: Failed to stop supplicant
08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/wifi: Can not initialize the vendor function pointer table
08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/WifiNative-HAL: Could not start hal
08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to start HAL
08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/WifiHW: Cannot open "/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf": No such file or directory
08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/WifiHW: Wi-Fi will not be enabled
08-09 14:27:17.821 1579-1622/? E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to start supplicant!
08-09 14:27:17.822 1579-1579/? E/WifiController: WifiControllerWifi turn on failed

Could this be the problem?

EDIT 2:

So I tried checking for permissions at run time but still no change.

```
  private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int wifi_state = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    int change_wifi_state = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
    int loc = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int loc2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int internet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.INTERNET);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (wifi_state != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    }
    if (change_wifi_state != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
    }
    if (loc2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (loc != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (internet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission.INTERNET);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty())
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I call this method in my onCreate. I'm still getting the call stack message that Controller Wifi failed to turn on as well, which I'm thinking to be the issue more and more.

Comment: Did you define your receiver in Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I now tried declaring the receiver in the manifest but still nothing changed. The only thing I think could be wrong is perhaps the Wifi is not being enabled correctly, as indicated by the callstack?

Comment: what is your test device android version ?

Comment: @ZohaibHassan it does not matter as he register receiver manually when activity starts

Comment: if the device android which you are testing equal or greater than lollipop then you have to request your permissions at run time https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I believe I'm running it on Nougat, so I'll try this and get back to you

Comment: Unfortunately, still does not seem to be working after requesting permissions at runtime. Edited my answer once more above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a mistake on my part, I was using the android emulator to test my app when I should have been using an actual phone.

Answer (score 0):

> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via
>   Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions

Try to add the missing permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Source : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Comment: Tried adding that permission in as well but still no change. I edited my answer above